# spaCy is_oov not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

`is_oov` does not appear to work for words that I know are in the vocabulary. Is it possible that this use-case is incorrect?

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

doc = nlp('I am sflmgmavknsaccasas dog cat bird bulbasaur')

[tok.is_oov for tok in doc]
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

- spaCy version: 2.0.9
- Platform: osx 10.13.4
- Python version: 3.6.4
- Models: en

Comment: see this https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1204 , seems `is_oov` is broken in last version!

Comment: Just for everyone's FYI this is only [partly broken](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1457). TLDR: `en_core_web_md` works, `en_core_web_sm` does not.

Answer (score 1):

You need the largest corpus for this to work.

So you need to load `en_core_web_lg` and not another version. Especially not the smaller versions (`sm`, `en`).

Answer (score -2):

I've tried to run your code, with the difference that I'm using the large English model and explicitly giving the path:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site- 
packages\en_core_web_lg\en_core_web_lg-2.0.0')
doc = nlp('I am sflmgmavknsaccasas dog cat bird bulbasaur')
[tok.is_oov for tok in doc]
[False, False, True, False, False, False, False]
```

As you can see, this works correctly. May I suggest that you try explicitly giving the path to the English model, just in case there is a problem with the symbolic link?

Comment: as evidenced here github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1204 many people are experiencing this issue and other errors would arise if the path to the library were incorrect